# Ipad: SplitViewController black DetailViewController

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

i have the following problem.

I'm developing an app with a splitViewController as the root controller. In the appDelegate i have this code in method  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
[self.window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
self.sendData = [[[SendData alloc] init] autorelease];

showEventsViewController.sendData = self.sendData;
LoginView *lvc = [[LoginView alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:nil];
lvc.delegate = self;

[splitViewController presentModalViewController:lvc animated:NO];
[lvc release];
return YES;
```

When the login is complete, i dismiss the loginView and i show the splitViwController.

Besides, my application needs to run only in landscape mode, so i have configured the plist in order to avoid only landscape mode and set this code in each view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Overriden to allow any orientation.
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    return YES;
if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    return YES;
return NO;
```

}

But when i run my app in portrait mode (the login view is shown right in landscape) and icomplete the login, the splitview is shown in landscape mode but the detailViewController is whole black (the master view is in landscape mode)

What is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, but how did you manage to send message to splitViewController that lvc has finished login?